# ngx-bootstrap's datepicker format value in reactive forms

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am working with this example:
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#reactive

As you see the value of {{ Form.value }} for 'date' is in the format "date": "2017-10-14T17:38:53.000Z", How it is posible to change that to "14/10/2017" as example, because that format is not passing my
regex validation!

I have tried playing around with the code example and I also read all the documentation about DatePicker Module but I wasn't able to figured out how to do it!

Answer (score 2):

You can use normal `javascript` date format method. When you select a date, trigger an event and format the date. Finally set the formatted date to the 
`formControlName`.

ForExample:

```
dateFormat("Fri Dec 01 2017 14:41:37 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");

dateFormat(date:any){
    let date = new Date(date),
    let month = ("0" + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2),
    let day  = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    let formattedDate=[day,month,date.getFullYear()].join("/");
    this.formName.patchValue({
      date:formattedDate }) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution is used for ngx daterangepicker used in reactive form and set basevalue for daterange picker.

`this.detailForm.controls['range'].setValue([new Date(this.projectData.startDate), new Date(this.projectData.endDate)]);`

for save data use this :

`if (this.detailForm.get('range').value) {
      this.projectData.startDate = this.datepipe.transform(this.detailForm.value.range[0], DateFormat.YYYY_MM_DD);
      this.projectData.endDate = this.datepipe.transform(this.detailForm.value.range[1], DateFormat.YYYY_MM_DD);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

this issue helped me with this same problem that your facing.
https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/2934

It basically says that with the object (in your case "date" with value "2017-10-14T17:38:53.000Z") you can use a method called .toLocaleDateString() since your object is a Date type.

ps.: I just realize that you are the one who create the issue on github(lol), anyway I'll let my answer here to help others :)

cya